# Symfony 2 - updating a user password

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I have built a add user form from my user entity form type.

The validation for this form is specified in validation.yml and works a treat.

However, I know wish to implement the functionality to edit a User.

The issue I am having is updating the User password fields as their are validation constraints on the field to not be left blank.

I would like to override this validation some how for editing a user or some method I can implement this logic (pseudo code example below):

```
If password is blank
    do not update the password field
else if password is populated
    trigger existing validation constraints as set in validation.yml
endif
```

I have scoured the web high and low and cannot seem to find a decent solution to a very common practice.

Controller Method:

```
public function editAction(Request $request, $id){
    $title = "Edit Player";
    $user = $this->getUser();

    //find the user objet by id
    $fetchedUser = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('BrsUserBundle:User')
        ->findOneById($id);

    //create form from the found user object
    $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(true), $fetchedUser);

    //set the data from the join on the form select
    $form->get('roles')->setData($fetchedUser->getRole()->current());

    $currentPassword = $fetchedUser->getPassword();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    // if($first = $request->get('user')['password']['first'] === "" && $second = $request->get('user')['password']['second'] === ""){
    //     $request->request->set('password',$currentPassword);
    // }


    // $form->getData()->setPassword('fdsfdsfdsffdsdfsfdsfdsfdsf');

    // print_r($form->getData()->getPassword());
    // var_dump($form->isEmpty());

    return $this->render('BrsUserBundle:Crud:edit.html.twig', array(
            'user'=>$user,
            'title'=>$title,
            'form'=>$form->createView()
        ));
}
```

User Form Type: (in progress so trying different things)

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {


            $builder
                ->add('username')
                ->add('roles','entity',array(
                    'class' => 'BrsUserBundle:Role',
                    'property' => 'role',
                ))
                ->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event){
                    $user = $event->getData();
                    $form = $event->getForm();
                    //var_dump($user['password']['first'] === '');
                    // $user['password']['second'] = "adssadasdsadsadsa";
                    // if($form->getData()->getPassword() && ($user['password']['first'] === '' && $user['password']['second'] === '')){
                    //     unset($user['password']);
                    // }

                    //print_r($user);
                    //$event->setData($user);
                    $form->setData($user);
                    // print_r($form->getData());
                    var_dump($form->isValid());
                })
                ->add('fname')
                ->add('lname')
                ->add('email')
                ->add('mobile')
                ->add('active')
                ->add('mentor')
                ->add('initialized');
 //$builder->add( 'first_name', 'text', [ 'constraints' => new NotBlank( ['message'=>'Please provide your First Name.'] ), 'label' => 'First Name' ] )
                $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
                    $user = $event->getData();
                    $form = $event->getForm();
                    print_r($form->getData()->getPassword());
                    $builder->add('password','repeated',array(
                        'type' => 'password',
                        'invalid_message' => 'The password fields must match.',
                        'options' => array('attr' => array('class' => 'password-field')),
                        'first_options'  => array('label' => 'Password'),
                        'second_options' => array('label' => 'Repeat Password'),
                        'required'=>false,
                    ));
                });

                $builder->add('save','submit');
    }
```

validation.yml

```
Brs\UserBundle\Entity\User:
properties:
    username:
        - NotBlank: ~
        - Length:
            min: 5
    fname:
        - NotBlank: ~
        - Length:
            min: 3
    lname:
        - NotBlank: ~
        - Length:
            min: 3
    email:
        - Email:
            message: The email "{{ value }}" is not a valid email address.
            checkMX: true
        - NotBlank: ~
        - Length:
            min: 5
    mobile:
        - NotBlank: ~
    active:
    mentor:
    initialized:
        - Type: \DateTime
    password:
        - NotBlank: ~
        - Length:
            min: 8
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Adam

Comment: You are over thinking this.  Make yourself a dedicated ChangePasswordFormType and controller.  Ask for the new password and update it.

Comment: I think so to, could you elaborate with an answer how you would do it please?

Comment: You can set a 'tempPassword' (non mapped) in your form builder, and make the logic on it, if the tempPassword is valide, set the plainPassword by usermanager...

Comment: @Yenne Info, Could you please elaborate on how to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In FormType :

```
(remove password field before)
$builder->add('temppassword','repeated',[
                        'type' => 'password',
                        'mapped'=>false,
                        'required'=>false
                    ]);
```

In controller :

```
$tempPassword = $form->get('temppassword')->getData();
/*make your logiq*/
if (yourlogic is good)
{
     $user->setPlainpassword( $tempsPassword );
}
```

Comment: I cant remove the password before from the form type as the form type is used for the Add User action.

Comment: you can pass a variable to the formType constructer that add/ or not the password field